# Mean calculations in data.table by grouping expected to be the same provide different results

Tags: r, data.table

I want to calculate the mean of a data.table column by grouping. I can figure out two different ways, that I expect they would be the same:

```
dt <- data.table(
    a   = 10:20
  , id  = c(1:3, 2,4,2,5)
  , text = letters[1:4]
)
dt[, mean_a  := mean(a, na.rm=T),         by = .(id)]
dt[, mean_a2 := lapply(a, mean, na.rm=T), by = .(id)]
dt[order(id)]

        a    id   text mean_a mean_a2
    <int> <num> <char>  <num>   <num>
 1:    10     1      a   13.5      10
 2:    17     1      d   13.5      10
 3:    11     2      b   15.4      11
 4:    13     2      d   15.4      11
 5:    15     2      b   15.4      11
 6:    18     2      a   15.4      11
 7:    20     2      c   15.4      11
 8:    12     3      c   15.5      12
 9:    19     3      b   15.5      12
10:    14     4      a   14.0      14
11:    16     5      c   16.0      16
```

The expected result is `mean_a`, different from `mean_a2`. I would expect to be exactly the same. Instead, `mean_a2` seems to pick up the first `a` instance that appears for a given `id`. What is going on?

Comment: You need to understand what lapply is doing. You are finding the mean of eac element instead of the mean of the group.

Comment: Compare `mean(1:10)` with `lapply(1:10, mean)`.

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, I clearly see your point, thank you. However, if it is the case, it does not explain why `mean_2` might be different from `a`, such as lines 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 9.

Comment: My main point is to be clear that the expectation that `mean(x)` and `lapply(x, mean)` *"to be exactly the same"* is flawed at its root, which I think is understood...

Comment: As to what's actually going on here, I agree it is surprising. `lapply` returns a `list`, which complicates things. If you had used `sapply` which simplifies its result to a vector, then I would expect `mean_2` would be the same as `a`, as in your previous comment. However, with the `list` result, my guess would have been that `mean_a2` would be a `list` class column, not a numeric. As it is numeric, my guess is the first element of the list is being recycled to the full length of the group, but I'm not sure if that's correct (it appears to be), and if so I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: But the takeaway is use `lapply` when you want a `list`. Don't use `lapply()` when you don't want a `list`. I don't feel a need to go digging in to `data.table` internals to try to figure out what it's doing when you give it a list but want an atomic vector.

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky, BUT not in such a sense that you could have expected the mean values to be the same. I honestly had expected in the lapply version to have a mean of one value in a, so being equal to a and not taking the first value only.

Let's illustrate and  force to message out your x in the apply function

```
dt[, mean_a2 := lapply(a, function(x) {
  message("Contents of x: ", x, "")
  foo <- mean(x, na.rm=T)
  foo
}), by = .(id)]

Contents of x: 10
Contents of x: 17
Contents of x: 11
Contents of x: 13
Contents of x: 15
Contents of x: 18
Contents of x: 20
Contents of x: 12
Contents of x: 19
Contents of x: 14
Contents of x: 16
```

In above you see what I expected, HOWEVER your true output is different.

```
    a id text mean_a2
 1: 10  1    a      10
 2: 11  2    b      11
 3: 12  3    c      12
 4: 13  2    d      11
 5: 14  4    a      14
 6: 15  2    b      11
 7: 16  5    c      16
 8: 17  1    d      10
 9: 18  2    a      11
10: 19  3    b      12
11: 20  2    c      11
```

It seems that the message breaks the assignment on reference in the group by.

Perhaps someone can clarify the reason why the output of x is different than the actual created value

Comment: Good point @Merijn, I will open an issue with data.table people. Thank you.